# Android transactions not showing in revenuecat dashboard

Tags: flutter, revenuecat

I have built a dummy flutter app and integrated it with revenue cat. Have put app in closed testing and followed all steps mentioned in the docs. Able to subscribe to plans and when plan is subscribed I am getting a mail to for payment confirmation (Sandbox). Problem is when I check firebase as well as revenue cat I am not seeing any android specific data there. For iOS it's working as expected. Any Pointers?

Comment: Not an answer, but a question: is there are tutorial for Flutter/Android? In their page they only mention iOS https://docs.revenuecat.com/docs/flutter

Comment: I have went through this several times. No luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Issue was package name in revenuecat was not same as in playstore. Strangely, for iOS we had same issue but it was working.

After changing package name, it immediately started working.

Comment: Hi Rajesh, what do you mean by package name? The bundle name?